# what is the options meaning in the repo url ----- Upgrading magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am trying to upgrade magento using the custom script

```
php -f pre_composer_update_2.3.php -- --root='<path/to/magento/install/dir>' --repo=https://repo.magento.com/ <options>
```

I understand the path to Magento install directory but can you please help me to understand the **options** meaning in the above code? please provide an example for the above code.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: I want to understand what is the meaning of  <options> in the repo url in last.